# StreamCorruptedException in ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to read a XML file from SD card and convert it in a Object type.
The issue is when I read the file using `FileInputStream`  and pass the `FileInputStream` object to   `ObjectInputStream` , I get an exception `StreamCorruptedException`.

```
//gets external storage dir
File externalstoragedir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 

//gets the path to file.
File externaltestcasefile = new File(externalstoragedir + "/" + FILENAME); 

//FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(externaltestcasefile); 

BufferedInputStream br = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(externaltestcasefile));

//Convert to ObjectInput Stream.
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(br);

//read the data from the ObjectInputStreamto Object.
Object fileData = ois.readObject();
```

Even I have used BufferInputStream but same exception is seen.

is there any way to convert the XML to object type directly before passing to `ObjectInputStream` ?

I have to use `ObjectInputStream` as per my project.

Any help is appreciable.

Any of the existing solutions did not help

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are trying to push a FileInputStream, reading from an XML file, into an ObjectInputStream. This will cause a StreamCorruptedException because the ObjectInputStream is expecting input in the java serialized object format [1], but it sees a character stream instead.

There are a few solutions to your problem:

If you are trying to grab an Android-specific object from XML, then you most likely should be getting it from the relevant function in the Android API.

If this isn't related to the Android API, there are a few packages out there that handle serialization to XML[2].

1: There is a canonical name for this, but I can't remember it off the top of my head.

2: [Serializing Java objects to xml and back (XML configuration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577742/serializing-java-objects-to-xml-and-back-xml-configuration)